# Rsyslog replace newline to <br/> in message part

Tags: linux, log4net, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I am using rsyslog to relay events from a machine to Loggly (cloud log management). I have an application running on that machine that logs to the local rsyslog by using the SyslogAppender of log4net. However, since some of the events are multi-line, thus contain new lines which are then replaced by the escape sequence `#012`. However, I would like to replace the newlines in the message part to `<br/>`. I have looked at rsyslogs property replacing [1] feature but I am not really sure if this is the right way. Furthermore, changing the implementation of the application would require some effort so I would like to avoid this way. So I am looking for a way to solve this issue "outside" of my application.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

[1] http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `#12`s is getting produced by `log4net` - not by syslog. If you don't want to change the application, you can use `sed` to replace the `#12` by `<br/>`:

```
sed 's/#12/\n/g' logfile
```